# get content of element after slicing his span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the next element:

```
<div id = "mydiv">
    abc
    <span>123</span>
</div>
```

`document.getElementById('mydiv').textContent` returns me: `abc123`

I want to get only the text of `mydiv` ('abc'). so I wonder if there is an option to use jquery in order to get it? maybe get all the content of an element except for span element..

and then getting his text..

p.s. I know I can wrap `abc` in span and then get it, but I wonder if there is another option to do it without changing my element..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/8Ab78/6/)

Try this ,

```
console.log($("#mydiv").clone() .children().remove().end().text());
```

Answer (score 1):

You must select yours DIV by ID, then run through its "childrens" property and check their nodeType (textNodes has 3);

```
var div = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var result = "";
for(var i = 0; i < div.length; i++){
    var node = div[i];
    if( node.nodeType === 3 ){
        result += node.data;
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've included jQuery you can do this

```
var p = $('#mydiv').clone();
p.find('span').remove();
console.log(p.text());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/V9NHV/)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('#mydiv span').text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to have more html elements inside your div, user regular expression to extract plain text after getting whole html content from div.

```
var re = /<.+>/;
var str = "abc<span>123</span>";
var newstr = str.replace(re, "");
```

Should give "abc"